# spark throws errors while reading hive view

Tags: hive, spark3

**Problem statement**

A hive view is created using beeline to restrict the users from accessing the original hive table since the data contains sensitive information.

For illustration purpose, let's consider a sensitive table as emp_db.employee with columns id, name, salary created through beeline by user 'userA'

```
create external table emp_db.employee (id int, name string, salary double) location '<hdfs_path>'
```

A view is created using beeline by the same user 'userA'

```
create view empview_db.emp_v  as select id,name from emp_db.employee'
```

From Ranger UI, we define a policy under Hadoop SQL Policies that will let 'userB' to access database - empview_db  and table - emp_v with SELECT permission.

**Steps to replicate**

1. ssh to edge node where beeline is available using userB
2. Try executing following queries

Select * from emp_db.employee;
desc formatted empview_db.emp_v ;

Above queries works fine without any issues.

3. Now, try using spark3-shell using userB

   ## spark3-shell --deploy-mode client

   Setting default log level to "WARN".
   To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
   23/07/08 01:24:09 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.masking.algo does not exist
   Spark context Web UI available at http://xxxxxxx:4040
   Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_xxx_xxx).
   Spark session available as 'spark'.
   Welcome to
         ____              __
        / **/**  ___ *****/ /**
       *\ / _ / _ `/ __/  '*/
      /***/ .__/_,*/*/ /*/_\   version 3.3.0.3.3.7180.0-274
         /*/
            
   Using Scala version 2.12.15 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181)
   Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
   Type :help for more information.scala> spark.table("empview_db.emp_v").schema
   23/07/08 01:24:30 WARN HiveClientImpl: Detected HiveConf hive.execution.engine is 'tez' and will be reset to 'mr' to disable useless hive logic
   Hive Session ID = b1e3c813-aea9-40da-9012-949e82d4205e
   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to fetch table employee. Permission denied: user [userB] does not have [SELECT] privilege on [emp_db/employee]
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:110)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.tableExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:877)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.tableExists(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:146)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.tableExists(SessionCatalog.scala:488)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.requireTableExists(SessionCatalog.scala:224)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.getTableRawMetadata(SessionCatalog.scala:514)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.getTableMetadata(SessionCatalog.scala:500)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2SessionCatalog.loadTable(V2SessionCatalog.scala:66)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogV2Util$.loadTable(CatalogV2Util.scala:311)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.$anonfun$lookupRelation$3(Analyzer.scala:1206)
     at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.$anonfun$lookupRelation$1(Analyzer.scala:1205)
     at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupRelation(Analyzer.scala:1197)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$13.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1068)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$13.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1032)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1228)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1227)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:208)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1228)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1227)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:208)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1032)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:991)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:208)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:227)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.$anonfun$resolveViews$2(Analyzer.scala:1012)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.withExistingConf(SQLConf.scala:158)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.$anonfun$resolveViews$1(Analyzer.scala:1012)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.AnalysisContext$.withAnalysisContext(Analyzer.scala:166)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$resolveViews(Analyzer.scala:1004)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$resolveViews(Analyzer.scala:1020)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$13.$anonfun$applyOrElse$47(Analyzer.scala:1068)
     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$13.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1068)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$13.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1032)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1032)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:991)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:208)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:227)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$execute$1(Analyzer.scala:223)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.AnalysisContext$.withNewAnalysisContext(Analyzer.scala:172)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:223)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:187)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:208)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:330)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:207)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:76)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:186)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:511)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:186)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:185)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:76)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:74)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:66)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$1(Dataset.scala:91)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:89)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.table(DataFrameReader.scala:607)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.table(SparkSession.scala:600)
     ... 47 elided
   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to fetch table employee. Permission denied: user [userB] does not have [SELECT] privilege on [emp_db/employee]
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1462)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1411)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1391)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_12.getTable(HiveShim.scala:639)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.getRawTableOption(HiveClientImpl.scala:429)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$tableExists$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:444)
     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$withHiveState$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:321)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:248)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:247)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:301)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.tableExists(HiveClientImpl.scala:444)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$tableExists$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:877)
     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:101)
     ... 151 more
   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException: Permission denied: user [userB] does not have [SELECT] privilege on [emp_db/employee]
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_req_result$get_table_req_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_req_result$get_table_req_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_req_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
     at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:88)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_table_req(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:2378)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_table_req(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:2365)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2047)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:206)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:213)
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.getTable(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:3514)
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.getTable(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1453)
     ... 165 more

Expected behavior - we want spark to behave just like beeline where SELECT * from  and DESC formatted  on view works fine without any errors.

The CDP 7.1.7 documentation link [https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.7/developing-spark-applications/topics/spark-interaction-with-hive-views.html?](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.7/developing-spark-applications/topics/spark-interaction-with-hive-views.html?%C2%A0)  describes 'Interacting Hive Views'. However, the explanation doesn't fit well with the behavior we see from spark3-shell for hive views.

Looking forward for feedback and inputs that may unblock my use case. Please let me know if  you need any further information.

Comment: Did you give file permissions about views table to your user